# how to use javascript to get visited link css styles

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, stylesheet

I would like to use javascript to style an element to look like a :visited link, without defining my own styles for visited links.  How can I access the browser's default style for visited links, so that I can define a matching style that I can apply to an element (e.g. by applying a class name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try opening the page in hidden `<iframe />`. I don't see another solution besides building extensions for the browser(s) to do what you want to do. I also don't know if you are putting too much effort into it.

It could be as simple as establishing some rules for your app.

For example, **new link** vs. *visited link*. The differences are obvious and don't depend on color either.